# Pass parameters to timer_Tick event

Tags: c#, events, parameters, timer

I'm wanting to pass some parameters to the event timer_tick in c# but I don't want to make them global variables. Is this possible?

I had a look round and came up with something like this:

```
//Where I start the timer
lift1Up.Enabled = true;
lift1Up.Tick += (sender, args) => lift1Up_Tick(sender, args, destination, currentFloor);
lift1Up.Start();

private void lift1Up_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e, int dest, int current)
{
    //my code      
}
```

Many thanks!
Luke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,but not like that. You can define a class by inheriting from [EventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int dest { get; set; }
    public int current { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to manually trigger `Tick` event and pass parameters like this:

```
lift1Up_Tick(this, new MyEventArgs { dest = 23, current = 100 });
```

And in tick event you can get this arguments:

```
private void lift1Up_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var args = (MyEventArgs)e;
    int dest = args.dest;     
}
```

I don't know is there a better way.To do this (manuel trigger) you can add another timer.Set it's interval then write this code inside of it's Tick event:

```
lift1Up_Tick(this, new MyEventArgs { dest = 23, current = 100 });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a lambda for your event handler, and access your local variables from there, the C# compiler will do the magic:

```
void StartTimer()
{
    EventHandler tickHandler = null;

    var destination = 5, currentFloor = 0;

    tickHandler = (sender, args) => 
    {
        if (currentFloor == destination)
        {
            lift1Up.Enabled = false;
            lift1Up.Tick -= tickHandler;

            MessageBox.Show("Arrived!");
        }
        else
            currentFloor++;
    }

    // start the timer
    lift1Up.Tick += tickHandler;
    lift1Up.Enabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use **Lambda functions**, as used in the example mentioned. Lambda functions are a form of nested function, in that they allow access to variables in the scope of the containing function. Lambda expression is defined as:

```
(input parameters) => expression; 
(input parameters) => {statement block};
```

So, you can execute any expression or statement block, like call method, with the visibility of all variables of the scope, including event variables, without need to make them global variables.